# What is the exact behaviour of INT instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, interrupt

Such as **x86** instructions :`push` can be **precisely** described by:

```
push:
sub esp, data_size
mov [esp], data
```

And `call` can be described by:

```
call:
push (eip+2)
jmp addr
```

**By knowing these, we would be totally clear about how these instructions affect stack, registers and flags** and I think it is crucial.

However, after going through "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual". and "i386 programmers' manual" I found nothing about the exact behaviour of INT instruction.

Now, I want to modify the stack after INT call, to make my program return to another place.

**So, what exactly INT did after it was called?**

(by programmer or hardware. I heard they act differently)

Thanks in advance!!

> ps:
>
> As far as I know, INT pushes eip, 4 general registers, eflags and
>   some weird things in some order.
>
> I observed that it consumed 6 bytes on stack when called by me,
>
> and it consumed 18 bytes when triggered by hardware.(like clock)
>
> supplement: my code
>
> 1. hook ivt 0x1ch(System Timer Tick) to my function [foo]
> 2. sti
> 3. jmp $
> 4. foo: print 'A'
>
> I check the stack at `jmp $` and just before entering `foo`

Comment: The behavior of the instruction is well documented in the instruction set references (based on the Intel docs): http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/INT%20n:INTO:INT%203.html

Comment: That HTML is an extract from Intel's volume 2 PDF.  You were looking in the right manuals, but I guess not in the right volume.

Comment: BTW, is `call` really `push (eip+2)` ? I mean, the `eip` is already pointing to next instruction after decode phase, so if you dissect it in the internal inter-phase way, then `push eip` `jmp arg` is correct. If you don't want to use the updated `eip`, then it it's `push eip+<instruction_size>` and instruction size depends on argument, `call` can have 2 (r32/[r32]), 5 (rel-imm32) or 7? bytes (far immediate variant).

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks! I just read it. I was not reading carefully enough and didn't notice it at first. It was my fault. I run under real, as the chapter says, 6bytes shall be used. But the behaviour it lists can't explain why 18bytes were actually used when interrupt is triggered by hardware.(Manual says the rule applies to all int/exceptions/NMIs)

Comment: We don't see your code, but it is possible that the asynchronous timer interrupt stopped your code while something else was using the stack (BIOS interrupt for example)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you! I arbitrarily assumed it was more about CPU infrastructure. So I read V1 and V3 and carelessly went through V2. I was quite harebrained and lax.

Comment: I suspect what you are missing is that `int 1ch` is called by the interrupt handler the BIOS installed for the `int 08h`. `int 08h` is in fact the interrupt vector that IRQ0 (timer interrupt) calls. So the overhead you are seeing on the stack is what Interrupt `08h` used before it called `int 1ch`. Try hooking `int 08h` (instead of 1ch) directly with your routine and you should notice a difference.

Comment: In essence a timer interrupt reaches the PIC, triggers IRQ0 which executes interrupt vector 08h. Interrupt vector 08h defaults to BIOS code that usually deals with the real time clock on the system and it does the equivalent to an `int 1ch` as part of its processing. That is the interrupt you hooked (the default software interrupt 1ch installed by the BIOS usually does nothing but an _IRET_). Think of interrupt 1ch as a user call back function called by interrupt 08h (system timer interrupt)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks！I checked a book named "PC-Interrupts" and found that you're right. I'll take a further look into that chained-int, for the book only gives some brief description. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I observed that it consumed 6 bytes on stack when called by me

From this line and from the tag "operating-system" I conclude that you've used the `int` instruction from the Real Address Mode. In this case the stack will hold 3 words at the start of the interrupt handler.

The 1st word pushed (highest in memory) is the `FLAGS` register, the 2nd word pushed is the `CS` register, and the 3rd word pushed (lowest in memory) is the `IP` register.

> Now, I want to modify the stack after INT call, to make my program return to another place.

You are free to write anything suitable in any or all of these 3 words.

- To return to a different address but still in the same code segment, you would write:

  ```
  mov word ptr [esp], OtherLabel
  iret
  ```
- To return with the CarryFlag set, you write:

  ```
  or word ptr [esp+4], 1
  iret
  ```

Comment: CF: `or word ptr [esp+4], 1` ... +6 is already beyond real mode 6 bytes of data.